# Nodemcu ESP8266 12-F storage

Tags: nodemcu

I have just started working with my Nodemcu and was wondering when you upload codes using Arduino IDE on the device, how can you delete them from the storage?

Would highly appreciate any clues.

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably a question for [arduino.se] rather than here.

Comment: upload a different one

Answer (score 0):

Tried a variety of methods and the following worked:

1. You must have python installed.
2. install the esptool package using pip.
3. esptool.py --chip esp8266 --port (write the port location esp connected) erase_flash
4. run 3 in terminal
5. storage is emptied successfully.